# Java program for code-formatting

Tags: code-formatting

Is there a program (Java program) to format code according to Java code format conventions?

Does an [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) task exist?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I think you can use system.out.printf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Ant external task for Jalopy.

- http://ant.apache.org/external.html
- http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/
- http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#adding-external-tasks

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will automatically do this for you if you tell it to. or at least it will do an awful lot of it. I doubt it would rename variables to meet the coding standard though.

Click on the properties for you project and look at the options under "Java Code Style"

You will have to open each file individually and save it though.

You can also install [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to enforce coding standards.